# How can I retrieve the value of the key on the basis of the value of email of a user in my Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is how my database looks like.]

Since I am new to firebase, please help me with this. The problem here is that email is a part of another key called user_profile that exits under the uid(which acts as a key) of the user.

Comment: so you want to find user profile with the value of email?

Comment: Aside from that: Please specify what language you're using and what post what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly easy using database queries. In this case you have a property `user_profile/email` that needs to match the value. So:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('users');
var query = ref.orderByChild('user_profile/email').equalTo('issidhant.k@gmail.com');
query.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(user) {
    console.log(user.key+': '+user.val().user_profile.displayName);
  });
});
```

To learn more read the [Firebase documentation on sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can get your email inside the UID

```
 DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference idRef = rootRef.child(uid).child("user_profile").child("email");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          String email  = datasnapshot.getValue(String.class);
          Log.e("email is:",""+email);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
```

remember, to get uid you must declare `mAuth`

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

mAuth = FirebaseAuth().getInstance();
```

`String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();` <---- This line will retun uid